# In Java, is checking if a value is greater than zero faster than checking if a value equals zero? If so, why?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I was implementing a snippet on Leetcode and my initial loop ran like this:

```
    //n and x are an integer and a double respectively
    long N = Math.abs((long)n);
    double result = 1;
    while(N != 0){
        if((N & 1) == 1){
            result *= x;
        }
        N = N >> 1;
        x *= x;
    }
```

The whole code took 2ms to run. I then changed `N != 0` to `N > 0` and the code took 1ms to run. Why was there a jump in runtime due to this change? In other words, how does Java implement `x != y` and `x > y`?

Comment: Did you test it just once? There will be time differences between each execution and the result ins´t really saying that there are major differences in terms of performance. It´s just a standard "this time it took x ms", next time it might be vica verse.

Comment: I think the flaw may be in your test...

Comment: Writing [micro-benchmarks in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java/513259) is a lot harder than you think. Your measurement is not as precise as you think.

Comment: Kevin is right. After running a lot more tests it looks like the runtime for both wavers between 1ms and 2ms. I think Leetcode provides the ceiling of the runtime as the official runtime and the actual runtimes must have been hovering somewhere around 1ms (so the 1ms and 2ms). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Probably because when jvm checks for `N > 0` it looks just for byte that represents sign and when jvm checks for `N != 0` it needs to go through all bytes in the variable.

Comment: Given that nowadays all operations are in 64 bits together and bytes are not loaded individually to the CPU, what you are describing is probably not applicable these days.

Comment: Difference can be in comparing one byte and comparing `n` bytes. Even if they all loaded in CPU in one time, they still need to be checked and that can make a difference in time measures.

Comment: Neither operation will take more than one clock cycle - it's a single machine instruction (on an IA-64). The difference doesn't really exist, the OP noticed that himself.